# Prove that $\sqrt m$ is irrational by showing that the set $\{n\in\mathbb N: n\sqrt m\in\mathbb N\}$ is empty

Tags: elementary-number-theory, radicals, rationality-testing

> Let $m\in\mathbb N$ be such that $m\neq k^2$ for all $k\in\mathbb N$. Prove that $\sqrt m$ is irrational by showing that the set $\{n\in\mathbb N: n\sqrt m\in\mathbb N\}$ must be empty.

Comment: How would you hope to do this? I have given previously a proof that $\sqrt{n}$ is irrational if $n$ is not a perfect square. Would this do?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If there were such an $n$, then $(n\sqrt{m})^2=n^2m$ would be the square of an integer. (But $m$ shouldn't be writable as $k^2$ for any $k$)